# Tomar correo de dispositivo android (android studio)

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando tomar el correo por defecto que tiene cada dispositivo **android** pero siempre me trae un valor nulo.

Alguien me podría indicar que puedo estar haciendo mal. Les dejo el código del `manifest` y del `MainActivity`

**Permisos Manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**MainActivity**:

```
AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) 
getSystemService(this.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
//AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) AccountManager.get(this);
Account account = getAccount(accountManager);

if (account != null) {
    emailAccount =  account.name;
    Log.e("email", ""+emailAccount);
}

 private Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
 Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 33);
}



 Account accounts[] = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
Account account;
//account = accounts [1];
if (accounts.length > 0)
    account = accounts[0];
else {
    account = null;
}
Log.e("email", ""+account);
return account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tu código me parece que es correcto**, obtienes las cuentas de tipo "Google" ("com.google) y obtienes la primera.

**El problema seguramente son los permisos, estos deben requerirse manualmente si tu dispositivo usa sistema operativo 6.0 o mayor.**

[Controlar los permisos de una aplicación en Android 6.0 y versiones superiores](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=es)

[Como solicitar permisos de la app](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es#java)

Este es un ejemplo para obtener el permiso `GET_ACCOUNTS` :

```
public class AccountsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "AccountsActivityTAG";
    private String wantPermission = Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS;
    private Activity activity = AccountsActivity.this;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accounts);

        if (!checkPermission(wantPermission)) {
            requestPermission(wantPermission);
        } else {
            getEmails();
        }
    }

    private void getEmails() {
        Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;

        // Getting all registered Google Accounts;
        // Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");

        // Getting all registered Accounts;
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();

        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s - %s", account.name, account.type));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(String permission){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission(String permission){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Get account permission allows us to get your email",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getEmails();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Permission Denied.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```